# Howto transfer internet-stream to raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc, streaming-video, web-browsers

I am using raspbmc with my TV.
I would like to transfer internet streams from different services to the raspbmc.
Most of those services are captcha protected.

The easiest way for me would be - to solve the captchas on the Desktop PC,
receive the link,
somehow transfer (Push?) the stream to the raspbmc.

Is there any popular solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use *.strm files. After putting a link to a stream to a *strm file - you can threat the *strm file as normal video.

Details are stated [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Internet_video_and_audio_streams) .

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PlayIt](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=118251) plugin for XBMC (RaspBMC). It has browser extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

This plugin supports major video streaming sites (YouTube, Vimeo, Dailymotion, SoundCloud etc.) If streaming site give you download link, you can send link to PlayIt on XBMC via context menu (right click).